# Is it possible to merge inbox and sent folders in Mail?

Tags: mail.app

I'm considering migrating to OS X and I have a question on configuring its Mail application. In my current setup, I use Thunderbird configured to keep all sent and received messages from all my POP3 accounts in a single inbox folder, so I can follow my conversations in a nice thread, without having to jump from inbox to sent back and forth. I hope I've described it clearly, if not - I am going for something like this:

[image: Sent and Inbox merged]

Would I be able to configure Apple Mail like this? I know I can just install Thunderbird for Mac and copy profile, but I would rather stick to default application if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

The layout is a bit different than in Thunderbird, but you can get threaded conversations by checking "Include related messages" in the Preferences panel:
[image: Screenshot of Preferences panel in Mail]

The result will be something like this:

[image: Screenshot of a conversation in Mail]

By choosing to "Use classic layout" you can get drop-downs for a thread, but it will only show messages from others, not from yourself. Your replies *are* shown in the preview pane on the bottom, though.

[image: Screenshot of conversation in Mail in classic view]

Edit: I just noticed this myself, but you can also click on the double arrows in the not-Classic view to show individual messages from others.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. On iOS, maybe - there are settings to select specific folders as Drafts or Sent or etc. - but in desktop Mail, you cannot select Inbox and change it to function as anything else (selecting a folder allows you to go to the Mailbox menu item and choose "Use this mailbox as..." but options are grayed out if an Inbox folder is selected).

I use Mail.app on mobile. I use Thunderbird on the Mac desktop. Minor complaints aside, I'm happier with that setup, because my mail works as I expect it to on my system - I've been using Thunderbird far too long to want to re-adjust my expectations for a desktop app.